# Why rowspan html does not work as expected?

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to create a table layout as shown in below image:

[image: https://imgur.com/c4M6gAM]

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td rowspan="2">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The actual result:

[image]

Comment: it actually does work, but your table row heights aren't tall enough.  if you add more text which makes the rows taller, or increase the row heights, you will see the result is correct. http://plnkr.co/edit/cWiAoMHYj2P5d0xDePr1?p=preview

Comment: Basically, because you are effectively not using row 2 at all (every column overlaps row 2 with another row in some way), row 2 is reduced to a single pixel high with the default heights.

Comment: It works, thank you very much!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
It works if we use height and width for td and tr
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
tr{
height:50px;
}
td{
width:30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
  </body>

</html>

</body>
</html>
```